# Cakephp3 Email Message

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Im trying to send an email not using templates, the email is sent with the right subject but the message is always blank.

```
public function sendEmail($token = null, $recipient = null)
{
    $path = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]";
    $controller = "/users/activate/";
    $message = $path . $controller . $token;
    $Email = new Email();
    $Email->profile(['from' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'transport' => 'default']);
    $Email->to($recipient);
    $Email->subject('Verification Email');
    $Email->message('test');
    //$Email->message($message);
    if ( !$Email->send() ) {
        $response = array('success' => false, 'message' => __('Error sending email', true),);
        $this->sendResponse($response);
    }
}
```

I've tried both a variable or plain text and it keeps sending the emails blank.

Any example of how to assign the message properly?

Comment: Hey I kept testing and found out this is the right way to assign the message:

      $Email->send($message)

Answer (score 0):

I kept testing and this is the correct way t assign the message to a simple email:

```
$Email->send($message);
```